# Trying to generate SQL Query at runtime. Syntax error only when generated

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dapper

As the title states I'm trying to generate an SQL Query at runtime, in order to not have to type out gigantic SQL queries for tables that have over 50+ rows. In a console app I came up with this code to generate a query:

```
public static string generateAutoIDInsert()
{
    Type T = Type.GetType("DapperDemo2.Models.Company");
    PropertyInfo[] properties = T.GetProperties();
    PropertyInfo last = properties.Last();
    var sql1 = '"' + "INSERT INTO Companies (";
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
    {
        if (property.Equals(properties[0]))
        { 
            continue; 
        }
        if (property.Equals(last))
        { 
            sql1 += property.Name;  
        }
        else
        { 
            sql1 += property.Name + ", "; 
        }
    }
    sql1 += ") VALUES (";
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
    {
        if (property.Equals(properties[0]))
        { 
            continue; 
        }
        if (property.Equals(last))
        { 
            sql1 += "@" + property.Name; 
        }
        else
        { 
            sql1 += "@" + property.Name + ", "; 
        }
    }
    sql1 += ");" + '"' + " + " + '"' + "SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() as int);" + '"';
    return sql1;
}
```

When run it looks like a working SQL Query. Yet when trying to actually save data using it I get a syntax error. Namely:

```
SqlException: Incorrect syntax near '+'.
```

I don't really know what's causing it seeing as the query looks the exact same as the query I used originally to test the basic CRUD application. Even if I copy over the output query from the console application directly into the CRUD app, it works.

Reason for not using entity framework for this is that I was requested to use dapper for speed.

EDIT for reopening: changing the + at the bottom to a ; does not fix the issue. This whole function is meant to literally create this:

```
"INSERT INTO Companies (Name, Adress, City, State, PostalCode) VALUES (@Name, @Adress, @City, @State, @PostalCode);" + "SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() as int);"
```

Which works

Comment: Why single quotes between the end of the INSERT query and the begin of the SELECT one? No need for them (as well at the beginning of the INSERT and end of the SELECT)

Comment: @gunr2171 The asker is creating the sql text with proper parameterization. They are not inserting values here.

Comment: I'm shocked. That something that doesn't happen often.

Comment: + " + " +  on the last line, @gunr2171

Comment: Your function is "meant to create" that sample, but what did it *really* create?

Comment: OT check out String.Join

Comment: Are you certain that you really need those quotes inside your generated string?

Comment: The most important thing here is to know the value of `sql1`. What is it?

Answer (score 1):

By using your sample code, the generate SQL command like this:

[image]

As we can see it contains `\"` and `+` in the SQL command, so, it will cause this error.

Try to use [SSMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/quickstarts/ssms-connect-query-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) create a SQL query, we can see that the insert statement should like this:

[image]

So, try to modify the generateAutoIDInsert method as below:

```
    public static string generateAutoIDInsert()
    {
        Type T = Type.GetType("WebApplication1.Models.Company");
        PropertyInfo[] properties = T.GetProperties();
        PropertyInfo last = properties.Last();
        var sql1 = "INSERT INTO Companies (";
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
        {
            if (property.Equals(properties[0]))
            { continue; };
            if (property.Equals(last))
            { sql1 += property.Name; }
            else
            { sql1 += property.Name + ", "; }
        }
        sql1 += ") VALUES (";
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
        {
            if (property.Equals(properties[0]))
            { continue; };
            if (property.Equals(last))
            { sql1 += "@" + property.Name; }
            else
            { sql1 += "@" + property.Name + ", "; }
        }
        sql1 += ");" + "SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() as int);";
        return sql1;
    }
```

Then, the SQL statement like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `+ " + " +` on the last line should probably be `+ ";" +`

Note that generating this each time will remove any benefits of Dapper - you should cache and reuse it.

Comment: This does not fix the issue
SqlException: Incorrect syntax near ' ; '
Also well the one that asked me to use dapper is being a dick about it but finds this okay, and I don't know a better way.

Comment: @Tim honestly, the first thing you need to do here is output the string that is being generated. If you'd show us that, it would be much easier to see the problem. Or just look at it in SSMS to see what looks wrong.

Comment: I did edit it in the original post but here it is again:
```
"INSERT INTO Companies (Name, Adress, City, State, PostalCode) VALUES (@Name, @Adress, @City, @State, @PostalCode);" + "SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() as int);"
```

Comment: @tim in the post, you edited in what it is *meant* to produce. That's not the same as what it *actually* produces. If you could edit what it *actually* produces into the question, it would help. The string *after* all the concatenations, so: not `"..." + "..."`, but the actual final value.

Comment: It is two strings actually, could that be issue? If so what do you recommend to get the "SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() as int);" in there?

Comment: @Tim it isn't two strings once you've concatenated them. That's kinda the point. We need to see what the final result is *after* you've added all the bits you're after. As a side note: when building strings like this, `StringBuilder` is a lot cheaper than constant concats - it avoids all the intermediate strings (use ToString() when you're done). But that's a secondary issue. We just want to know what `sql1` is *right before* you `return sql1;`

Comment: I'll get back to you on that in a moment.

Comment: When imported into a view and printed there it simply shows this 

`"INSERT INTO Companies (Name, Adress, City, State, PostalCode) VALUES (@Name, @Adress, @City, @State, @PostalCode);" + "SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() as int);" `
Producing the same syntax error

Comment: @TimVerhees usually a batch of commands like that should be supported by all database providers, but here it's unclear about what provider you're using. That might be the one that does not support it, such as instead we may have to use a `GO` statement in-between, I'm not so sure. Basically you can take it as the cause, actually open some external GUI client of your database to execute and reproduce that error, find out how to run multiple commands in a batch for that kind of database provider...

Comment: I'm using SQL server but as stated before, the SQL query works just not when generating it through a function then it suddenly has a syntax error.

Comment: @TimVerhees "When imported into a view and printed there it simply shows this"  - you should have *one* string as the result; no view/whatever is going to break it randomly into two (around here: `Code);" + "SELE`). As such, until I see a single **one** string (not two), anything else is ... impossible to comment on.